# How to fix Operation Denied when deploying new update to the staging using AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab

Hi developers I have problem regarding AWS issue when deploying new update to the staging. I got error on my **CI/CD** my gitlab **JOBS** indicates that current user does not have the correct permission.

> ERROR: The current user does not have the correct permissions. Reason: Operation Denied. The security token included in the request
> is invalid. ERROR: The current user does not have the correct
> permissions. Reason: Operation Denied. The security token included in
> the request is invalid. You have not yet set up your credentials or
> your credentials are incorrect  You must provide your credentials.
> (aws-access-id): ERROR: EOFError - EOF when reading a line Cleaning up
> project directory and file based variables 00:00 ERROR: Job failed:
> exit code 1

This is my first time to encounter this error on my gitlab. What does this mean and how to fix this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: What AWS service do you try to use? Do you use AWS CLI in GitLab? Per the error message, looks like you haven't set your AWS credentials in GitLab CI environment variables (check it out, it's possible that even if you did set it, that it's not visible in the branch you are currently using)

Comment: @Caldazar, What things I already did. I created new user in IAM and copy the Access and after that The AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY I set it on the Gitlab repository